# What does "sell x for value" mean?

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence *"We sell you clothes for value."*, what does "for value" mean?

Is the above sentence even grammatically valid?

Comment: Where did you see this? It doesn't make sense to me, out of context.

Comment: @MattЭллен, on a store banner.

Comment: On a store banner where? Which country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the sentence means: "We sell you clothes at cost", i.e. that they sell without taking a profit.

In my experience, the formulation is not commonly used in the US.

Answer (score 0):

If a store uses this "sound bite," as it were, to attract customers, the store is saying in effect

> "Our store gives you the best bang for your [clothing] buck."

In other words, you as a customer get high value for the least money.  The banner, as you describe it, is not terribly imaginative, but most potential customers would probably get the point.

Comment: -1 I would have to question whether using a strongly US colloquialism *best bang for your buck* is really the best way of explaining another expression to a non-US resident.

Comment: I did not think to check the OP's profile.  My bad.  No offense taken; no offense intended.  I just hope you don't think there's something crude or untoward about the phrase.  "Bang," after all, can have a sexual connotation, but in this expression the referent is an explosion of fireworks--you know, the biggest explosion for the fewest dollars. By the way, how do you know the OP wouldn't understand the saying?  Aren't you perhaps being a little patronizing?  In the words of Jerry Seinfeld, "I'm just saying . . .."

Comment: No, I didn't think of the sexual connotation, nor did I know that it referred to an explosion. And, no I don't know that OP wouldn't understand it - he may do: I don't know what OP's native language is. I suspect he may have seen the banner in SG: it has an Anglo-Chinese feel to it. I wasn't intending to be patronising - it just seemed so specifically a US phrase that I wouldn't be surprised at non-US English speakers not understanding it. I had to think twice about it. And who's Jerry Seinfeld?

Comment: Jerry Seinfeld is an American comedian, most famous I suppose for his sitcom "Seinfeld."  A segment of one of his shows featured the phrase "I'm just saying . . .," which is never really completed, but just trails off . . ..  The phrase was invoked when his interlocutor became defensive over something he said, as if by simply saying "I'm just saying" the offense would be magically smoothed over, which of course it was not.  An equivalent saying might be, "Hey, chillax.  I didn't mean to get your feathers all ruffled!"  Feel free to remove the -1, but only if you've a mind to.

Comment: @TrevorD - I don't think there's anything particularly American about the expression "best bang for your buck".  It's commonly used where I come from; which is a LONG way from USA.  Maybe not in UK, but only because they have quid, not bucks.